# Figuring Out Difference Between Groupby Operations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hi I'm dealing with this data frame: [image: train_cf]

I wanted to groupby this by subreddit, then use label as the aggregating column. My understanding of groupby is that these two lines are equal:

(A)   df.groupby('grouping column').agg({'aggregating column':'agg function'})

(B)   df.groupby('grouping column')['aggregating column'].agg('agg function')

But I get slightly different results with method A producing a multi-level index. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my understanding and why?

[image]